Add smooth skin filter in Android from bitmap?
i am react native developer now i use react native webrtc and get VideoFrame to my java class then convert it to bitmap then i dont understand how can i make bitmap to look like smooth skin like reduce texture detail or make skin look bright naturally (i try with increase brightness and contrast but result it unnatural) can anyone guide me please
